# Error message for deploying Django app to Azure

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, django-apps

Is anyone able to explain why I'm getting this error message when trying to deploy my django-python app to Azure via the VS Code Azure Tool Extension?

"This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU."

I'm on a free trial with Azure.

I followed the instructions from this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/django-deployment/6-deploy-azure but have not been able to proceed past the 'create web app' stage.

Answer (score 0):

> "This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU."

The error means that you've reached the maximum number of limit for the resources allowed to use in that specific location. To resolve this issue, you need to choose a different region other than this or SKU that has available resources.

Or you can increase your instance quota for that region by raising a support request to the Microsoft support by visiting **Usage + quotas** under subscriptions in Azure as shown below and it is clearly detailed in [Doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-resource-quota.md#solution).

*Note*: As you are using free trial, I would suggest you try with the different region.

[image]

As you already given, I tried the same requirement using this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/django-deployment/6-deploy-azure) and it worked as expected.

*Created a web app & database, added the Postgress SQL database details such as DB Name, Host, Password as follows.*

[image]

*Once it is done, SSH into website for migrating the* `.py` *file as detailed in the above Doc.*

[image]

***Able to run the Django web app successfully:***

[image]